# Mocking callbacks in Laravel 4 (Mockery)

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, mockery

I'm currently writing tests for a package in Laravel 4.

I am mocking the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` which works nearly all the time except when a `where` method uses a callback, I cannot check if the methods inside the callback are called.

I was hoping one of you could shed some light.

```
$query = \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder', function ($mock) {
    /** @var \Mockery\Mock $mock */
    $mock->shouldReceive('where');
    $mock->shouldReceive('orWhere')->twice();
});
```

And the actual `where` method that should call `orWhere`. **Note:** That builder mock gets passed to the class below.

```
$builder = new LaravelBuilder($query);
```

Which then calls `$builder->filter()` which contains the below code.

```
$this->query->where(function ($query) use ($filterData) {
    /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query */
    foreach($filterData['columns'] as $colData) {
        /** @var \Samvaughton\Ldt\Column $column */
        $column = $colData['column'];

        // See if this column is searchable
        if (!$column->isSearchable() || !$colData['searchable']) continue;

        // If the individual column term is empty, use the main term
        $term = (empty($colData['term'])) ? $filterData['term'] : $colData['term'];

        // Actually apply the filter
        $query->orWhere($column->getSqlColumn(), "LIKE", "%{$term}%");
    }
});
```

The main part is the bottom bit `$query->orWhere`, the PHPUnit tests fail every time as it doesn't run the `orWhere` even once. Before you say that it might not reach the execution of it due to `continue`, the data I am passing will allow this.

I suspect this is due to how I am mocking the `where` method in the first place. If I include an `exit` before the `foreach` it does not execute indicating that it doesn't even run anything inside the callback. I know that is the default behaviour but how do I get Mockery to run the same/similar callback?

I have tried using partial mocks, using `shouldExpect` but don't fully understand it. I've also tried searching around but no luck with this scenario.

Would be great if I could learn how to use mockery within callbacks.

Answer (score 5):

OK so I think this can be done a better way, but I resorted to partially mocking Laravel's query builder.

*See line 324 in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`*

When using a closure Laravel spawns a new query builder which also needs to be mocked. Here's the code that worked:

```
$query = \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder', function ($mock) {
    /** @var \Mockery\Mock $mock */
    $mock->makePartial();
    $mock->shouldReceive('where')->once()->passthru();
    $mock->shouldReceive('newQuery')->andReturn(
        \Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder', function ($mock) {
            /** @var \Mockery\Mock $mock */
            $mock->makePartial();
            $mock->shouldReceive('orWhere')->twice();
        })
    );
});
```

I needed to use `makePartial()` so the query builder retained its original functionality for closures (which is not true to unit testing) so this isn't the best solution. From here I mock the `newQuery` method which is called to spawn a new query builder instance which I then mock in a similar format.

Comment: This really helped me!  I can't find anything in the Mockery docs about passing a closure as the second argument to `mock`.  How did you know to do this?